# Website opens as android app, but cannot interact

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, apk

So I tried converting the site I am working on to an android app using android studio

App was built successfully, no errors, opens when clicked but just stays static. I cannot interact with it..
It just stays on the main page, no interaction.
cannot swipe up/down/left/right
layout is not correct
cannot click the search box
the main site does adapt to different screen sizes

can you help me diagnose it?

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context=".MainActivity">

<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webView" />

<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </ListView>




</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package tech.radhelper.radhelpertech;

  import android.app.ListActivity;
  import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.Menu;
  import android.view.MenuItem;
  import android.webkit.WebSettings;
  import android.webkit.WebView;
  import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


 public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
      private WebView myWebView;
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl("https://radhelper.tech/");
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(myWebView.canGoBack()) {
        myWebView.goBack();
    } else
        super.onBackPressed();

   }

}
```

AndroidManifest.xmml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="tech.radhelper.radhelpertech">
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses- 
 permission>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

 </manifest>
```

Comment: This URL is not working on browser why?  :  https://radhelper.tech/

Comment: I can open it with mine.. can you try again?

Comment: This site can’t be reached
radhelper.tech took too long to respond.

Comment: don't use this : ListActivity , use this :  AppCompatActivity

Comment: Were  you able to open the site? Ok sir.. will try it..

Comment: i got it to work with the AppCompatActivity but I needed to change some parts in the main.xml

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work by changing  ListActivity to AppCompatActivity

and then changing the activity_main.xml

the code I use is:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

  <WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

I wrap the content instead of filling/match parent..

thanks to Abhinav Gupta for the help.. Cheers bai!